# How to build a classification tree with only binary splits in each feature variable (preferably in R)?

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, cart-analysis

I have been using rpart to train a supervised decision tree model, with binary responses. The problem with the results is that some features get split multiple times in a non-monotonic way. For instance, feature A might be split into three intervals, [0,0.4],[0.4,0.6],[0.6,1], corresponding to the following responses respectively, -1,1,-1. I would prefer that each feature gets split once and in a binary way. Is there a way to do that in R?

An illustrating example:

Suppose I am interested in predicting college dropout rate from SAT score. Then the tree or rpart package in R might give me the following model:

```
1. SAT > 1100: no dropout
2. SAT <= 1100:
  3. SAT > 900: dropout
  4. SAT <= 900: no dropout
```

While this might be the best binary tree model given the training data. I want to inject my domain knowledge that the relation between SAT score and dropout probability should be monotone, and enforce that there is a single SAT threshold for determining the dropout probability.

So my question is if there is a way to enforce monotonicity in the sense above in R.

Comment: You may also try to ask in cross validated if there is no reply in SO.

Comment: I think you have not fully understood the tree algorithm. I recommand you to control 'rpart.control(cp=0.05))' in rpart function

Comment: Basically, classification trees know how to do (A) an optimal binary data split and then apply this rule iteratively. You might modify this by the following: "Do (A), then remove the relevant input variable chosen by (A), then apply this modified rule iteratively. The workhorse in "rpart" is a C function, so I am afraid there is no direct way to apply this modification within "rpart".

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the pessimistic answer. In fact the problem I had is not redundant features, but rather one feature that gets split multiple times. I will update my question with an example.

Comment: The first split is the best. (Setting maxdepth=1 in rpart will stop after it). If you want multiple monotone splits, you could use isotonic classification trees or isotonic piecwise constant regression. But still not sure about the setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [party](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) package, you can enforce single split there

```
library(party)
library(survival)
plot(ctree(status  ~ time1,  rats2), type = "simple")
```

[image]

```
plot(ctree(status  ~ time1,  rats2, controls = ctree_control(stump = T)), type = "simple")
```

[image]

Comment: where are these values coming from?

Comment: @val it's a data set in the survival package